# Is there a proper way to set up a copy-on-write based build env that use your live / as base files?

Tags: development, chroot

I'm trying to set up a build environment using chroot, but instead of downloading ubuntu base files, I want to use my live `/` as base files for the chroot and use c-o-w to redirect any changes made in the chroot to other folder. So I come up with these

```
sudo mkdir /var/chroot/build/{root,cow,ubuntu}
sudo mount --bind / /var/chroot/build/root
sudo mount --bind /proc /var/chroot/build/root/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /var/chroot/build/root/dev/pts

sudo mount -t overlayfs -o upperdir=/var/chroot/build/cow,lowerdir=/var/chroot/build/root overlayfs /var/chroot/build/ubuntu
sudo chroot /var/chroot/build/ubuntu
```

It works almost perfectly except that contents of both `/proc` and `/dev/pts` are not visible inside the chroot although they are visible outside the chroot. Im guessing that's the limition of overlayfs when you set up chroot this way

So I want to know is there a proper way to do this? I found a nice sandbox app called [arkose](https://launchpad.net/arkose) which does almost what I want to do here but it doesn't let you keep the changes, once you exit the chroot, all files in c-o-w dir will be wiped out, which is not what I want

Comment: Check this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174277/chroot-with-unionfs-fuse-cant-access-dev